# Any way to let VSCode idle in background when closed

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

The only reason I am using sublime text instead of VSCode is that I often open up tiny files for a few seconds, and sublime opens instantly no matter what, while VSCode needs a second or so to start. I can however open new files when I have started it nearly instantly. Is there a workaround, so that I can let it idle in the background after I close the window, similar to skype?

Comment: So dont close it.

Comment: @Keltari Yeah I figured out that. But is there any way to do it without letting something linger in my taskbar?

Answer (score 0):

Since your comment said you would find it acceptable to *not* close the application, then there are options.  There are programs that will *minimize* other programs to the task tray.

I havent used these programs in many years, but you can google for them.  Here is one [program](https://www.actualtools.com/titlebuttons/minimize_to_system_tray_any_program.shtml) that is supposed to be compatible with Windows XP to 10.  This one is not free, but has a free trial.  However, you *may* be able to find a free one, as I remember them existing in the past.